# Refresh token - Rest Integration Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, connected-apps, auth-provider

I have been googling a lot about the fact how to get a refresh token.
I have rest integration between salesforce to salesforce and it is working fine. After few hours not using the service I get this message in my debug log : `message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`
I totally understand why it is happening ( cause every access has some time limit ). Now i want to request for the refresh token ( I understood by reading multiple articles. [sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)). In order to request for a refresh token, we should pass some parameters as mentioned below.

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.salesforce.com/ 
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0
QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&refresh_token=***your token here***
```

But just wanted to know that from where I get  &refresh_token=***your token here*** mentioned in the above sample code.

The rest integration is setup using Named credentials and Auth providers.

As a work around now, when the session is expired every time, I go to connected app and re-authenticate and my code works just fine.

My goal here is, when i face this Session Expired message, i should be able refresh the token withing the same class where i am invoking the rest service so that other piece of logic works fine.
please let me know if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: Please tell me client id and client secret are not the actual client ids and secrets of your organization !

Comment: If you are using named credentials it should be managing it for you. If you are making soap calls then there is a bug when the acces token expires where it does not refresh. If you call a rest endpoint first it will grab a new access token

Comment: As your secret key is still visible in the edition history, if it was a real key which I suspect, I **seriously** advise you to deactivate **asap and definitely** this connected app  (or regenerate a key but I'm not sure if it's possible) because those credentials could let anyone access and edit your org data / metadata

Comment: @emmanuel Nopes that’s just the dummy code I got from salesforce documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eric you are correct. using naming conventions does manages the refresh logic.
However i was wrong while selecting the scopes. initially I had selected as follows.

Under Named Credentials ==> **Scope = full**
later changed it to **full refresh_token**

**OAuth remained same.**

Connecte App: **Selected OAuth Scopes ==> full and refresh_token,offline_access**

This solved my problem.